# Google Chrome DevTools Font Rendering

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, fonts, chromium

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and chromium 52.0.2743.116. DevTools Font rendering is so annoying. I also tried chrome 53. the result was the same.
Is there anyway to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Annoying - how? How should it be?

Comment: @james: I can't spot what you seem to mean. Can you maybe highlight the example(s) on a screenshot and include it in your question?

Comment: @james it's different because it's a different font.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be asking more for a feature change in Chrome than anything to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering is not broken at all. What you see is the HTML code showing up in a different, monospace font compared to e.g. tab titles.

If it really is an issue, you can try a different devtools UI theme as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473766/changing-developer-tools-font-face-family

In short, the steps are:

1. Enable devtools experiments at `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments`, restart Chrome
2. Allow custom UI themes in devtools settings
3. Browse [devtools themes](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/devtools%20theme) and pick one

Comment: Thanks. I installed "DevTools Author" Extension and it changed the font.